# What is the purpose in using infinity rather than finite in set union?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, set-theory, intuition

In measure theory (and also in probability theory): I came across the third rule, which is countable union and can be written as follows

if $A_i \in A$ for all i $\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \in A$

Although I understood technically, I cannot able to get an intuition of defining the property *in the way* mentioned above. *What is the issue* if I define it in the countable/finite sense as follows?

If $A_1,A_2 \in A$ then $A_1 \cup A_2 \in A$

If I am correct, the latter way of writing can be naturally extended to the former one. I may be surely missing something. What is it?

Comment: Compare "If $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb N$ then $a_1+a_2 \in \mathbb N$". Do you think you can conclude from that that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \in \mathbb N$? (Answer: No. You can only conclude that for each finite $k$, $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i  \in \mathbb N$.)

Comment: Closure under finite unions does **not** imply closure under infinite unions (contra your claim at the end). For example, let $A$ be the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $A$ is closed under finite unions, but clearly not under infinite unions.

Comment: Since you mention "countable / finite", note that infinite sets can be [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) as well. In particular $\Bbb N$ is countable, so all unions you mention are countable unions. There exist infinite sets that are not countable, such as the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$. Measures are only closed under countable unions (i.e. finite and countably infinite unions), not under unions of larger cardinality.